# IDX10214: Audience validation failed error when securing asp.net mvc with Keycloak

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, keycloak

I'm not very familiar with ASP.net. I have followed the tutorial in this [link](https://github.com/dylanplecki/KeycloakOwinAuthentication/wiki/ASP.NET-MVC-Tutorial/) in order to secure an asp.net mvc application with Keycloak. Keycloak is running on localhost. When I click on About, it properly  redirects to Keycloak login page without any problem. The following error appears when I enter my username and password correctly and it wants to redirect to show the contents of "About" page:

> IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'account'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'null' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null, app'.
>
> Exception Details:
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException:
>   IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'account'. Did not
>   match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'null' or
>   validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null, app'.

When I disable audience validation flag using "DisableAudienceValidation = true", signature validation failed error will be raised:

> DX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match 'kid':
>   '87783715-a04c-42c6-b400-827febc23d12',  token:
>   '{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT","kid":"87783715-a04c-42c6-b400-827febc23d12"}.{"jti":"665f8127-53ca-4e88-ad23-c9c18e5a1ac1","exp":1559327065,"nbf":0,"iat":1559325265,"iss":"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo","aud":"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo","sub":"dc6ea95d-c1b9-42c4-8998-49bf7f001c3b","typ":"Refresh","azp":"app","auth_time":0,"session_state":"8406120f-9609-457b-8603-3df4e300ee8b","realm_access":{"roles":["offline_access","admin","uma_authorization","user"]},"resource_access":{"account":{"roles":["manage-account","manage-account-links","view-profile"]}},"scope":"openid
>   email profile"}'.
>
> Exception Details:
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException:
>   IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match 'kid':
>   '87783715-a04c-42c6-b400-827febc23d12',  token:
>   '{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT","kid":"87783715-a04c-42c6-b400-827febc23d12"}.{"jti":"665f8127-53ca-4e88-ad23-c9c18e5a1ac1","exp":1559327065,"nbf":0,"iat":1559325265,"iss":"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo","aud":"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo","sub":"dc6ea95d-c1b9-42c4-8998-49bf7f001c3b","typ":"Refresh","azp":"app","auth_time":0,"session_state":"8406120f-9609-457b-8603-3df4e300ee8b","realm_access":{"roles":["offline_access","admin","uma_authorization","user"]},"resource_access":{"account":{"roles":["manage-account","manage-account-links","view-profile"]}},"scope":"openid
>   email profile"}'.

I tested this app with my company Keycloak server which was running on https and it was ok, but when I test it with a Keycloak server on localhost it raises these errors. Then I compare the setting between Keycloak server of my localhost and the company's Keycloak. All the settings was the same.

This is my Startup.cs:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    const string persistentAuthType = "AspnetApp_cookie_auth";

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = persistentAuthType
    });
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(persistentAuthType); 

    app.UseKeycloakAuthentication(new KeycloakAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = "app",
        ClientSecret = "my-client-secret-key",
        VirtualDirectory = "", 

        Realm = "demo", // Don't change this unless told to do so
        KeycloakUrl = "http://localhost:8080/auth/",

        SignInAsAuthenticationType = persistentAuthType, 
        AuthenticationType = "AspnetApp_keycloak_auth", 
        //DisableAudienceValidation = true,
    });
}
```

And this is my HomeController.cs:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, @M. Jones , please copy/paste your errors directly onto this post, rather than providing links to them.

Comment: @natn2323
Hi, I did it as you said.

Comment: anyone doesn't know any solution to this error?